# How to Change the Format of the Email Template Sent with Webforms

Tags: 7, forms, webforms, emails

Ok, so I have a customer that has a ridiculously long form that individuals need to complete to apply for funding, but the email that is getting sent to our customer as well as each individual is not easy to read at all.

I have already installed MailSystem and MimeMail, so it is set to send in Full HTML, but it's still not that clear.

Is it possible to change the format so that the answer/response to each field is located below the field label? If possible, is this something that is relatively easy to do?

What about adding a line break between each field (label and response) so they aren't all one long list without any space to help distinguish between each one?

Any assistance with this would be GREATLY appreciated! We have a ton of nonprofit customers that all have similar forms and it would be very beneficial to have this option.

If you need any further clarification, just let me know.

Thank You!!

Nicole

Answer (score 1):

Go to: `node/%nid/webform/emails/%mid` and there is a fieldset (E-MAIL TEMPLATE) where you can define your own email template (per mail account) by using all available tokens and by writting pure html (like `<p>, <strong>` etc) within the text-area. Don't forget to select "Custom Template".

[Read more](https://www.drupal.org/node/1337488)